Asymptotic estimate from integral representation of modified Bessel function
While trying to prove
$$\sum_{n \leq x} d(n) = x \log x + (2\gamma - 1) x + O(x^{1/3} \log x) \tag{1}$$
using Voronoi's formula, I had to use the estimate
$$K_0(x) \ll e^{-x} \tag{2}$$
as $x \to \infty$, where $K_0$ is the Bessel K function for $\nu = 0$. This can be easily shown once one has the integral representation
$$K_0(x) = \int_0^{\infty} \mathrm e^{-x \cosh t} \mathrm dt. \tag{3}$$
How can one show $(3)$ from the original definition of $K_0$ ?

Here is a full proof: https://jahandideh.iut.ac.ir/sites/jahandideh.iut.ac.ir/files/files_course/bessel_0.pdf

@Zima. Thanks for the link !

Thanks a lot! Much appreciated!
